# What is the relationship between the Galilean group and the Poincaré group?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, galilean-relativity, poincare-symmetry

What is the relationship between the [Galilean group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation#Galilean_group) and the [Poincaré group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group)?
Are they siblings within the Lie group? Or does the Poincaré group contain the Galilean group as a subgroup?

I'm not so much interested in the Galilean group being the limit of the Poincaré group for c -> inf.

Comment: The Galilean group is the [group contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_contraction) of the Poincaré, not a subgroup. Why do you declare you are not interested in the only meaningful answer to your question?

Comment: Thanks. Because I already knew the c to infinity relationship. Would you call those groups siblings?

Comment: ***No***! They don't share a common ancestor. Several  of commutation relations have been smashed. A group contraction from A to B clearly designates B as a "child" of A, or, rather, an amputated version of A, just as classical mechanics is an amputated version of QM, or NR classical mechanics an amputated remnant of relativistic mechanics.

Comment: What is *"Are they siblings within the Lie group"* supposed to mean? What is "the Lie group"? What does it mean to be *siblings*?

Comment: Thanks Cosmas. If we take the open segment (0, 1) and 1 as analogy, the answer seem to suggest that because 0.99999... = 1, 1 is the amputated remnant of (0, 1). While (0, 1) and 1 are clearly distinct. Neither could 1 be considered a child of (0, 1). Is this a fair assessment?

Comment: Thanks ACuriousMind. I guess I meant siblings within the set of Lie groups. If that makes more sense.

Comment: Your "amputated remnant" paradigm is fair and sound. I don't know how to unify the two in a common group structure. How one names this structure in kinship terms is  likely subjective. Mathematicians call it group contraction, and physicists Wigner- Inönü contraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is assumed you have appreciated Inönü, E.; Wigner, E. P. (1953), ["On the Contraction of Groups and Their Representations"](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.39.6.510) *Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci.* **39** (6): 510–24, and the super-helpful Gilmore text in [Group contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_contraction).

Very crudely, the Poincaré Lie algebra,
$$
[J_m,P_n] = i \epsilon_{mnk} P_k ~, \qquad  [J_i, P_0] =  0 ~, \\
 [K_i,P_k] = i \delta_{ik}  P_0 ~, \\
[P_0,P_i]=0 \qquad [P_i,P_j]=0 \qquad [K_i, P_0] = -i P_i ~, \\
 [J_m,J_n] = i \epsilon_{mnk} J_k ~, \qquad 
 [J_m,K_n] = i \epsilon_{mnk} K_k ~, \\
 [K_m,K_n] = -i \epsilon_{mnk} J_k  ~,
$$
given relabelings $E=-cP_0$ and $K_i=cC_i$  contracts upon $c\to \infty$ to  the Galilean algebra,
$$
[J_m,P_n] = i \epsilon_{mnk} P_k ~, \qquad 
 [J_i,E]=0 \\
 [C_i,P_j]= 0,~\\
[E,P_i]=0, \qquad 
 [P_i,P_j]=0, \qquad 
 [C_i,E]=i  P_i \\  
[J_m,J_n] = i \epsilon_{mnk} J_k ~,  \qquad 
 [J_m,C_n] = i \epsilon_{mnk} C_k ~, \\
 [C_i,C_j]=0 .
  $$

There are a few subtleties and wrinkles, extensions, to be sure, which I gather you are not focussing on, but,  crudely, the third and the last commutation relations trivialized/collapsed. (There is more, but I am oversimplifying...).
This collapse/amputation is the Lie algebraic manifestation of a group contraction.

Comment: Thanks Cosmas. I will mark your answer as the solution. Could you take a look at my comment above?